# RuntimeWarning не работает filter

Tags: django

И так цель вывести все даты (список ссылок) по которым были созданы какие-либо посты, переходим по ссылке получаем все посты, созданные в данную дату.

Начинается всё с `all_dates.html`. Здесь я передаю аргумент (дату)

```
{% for date in dates %}
    <h1><a href="{% url 'list:detail_date' date.created_at|date:'Y-m-d' %}">
    {{ date.created_at|date:'Y-m-d' }}</a></h1>
{% endfor %}
```

views.html

```
@login_required
def all_dates(request):
  dates = Todo.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('-created_at')
  return render(request, 'list/all_dates.html', {'dates':dates})
```

Выглядит всё это дело так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
urls.py

```
app_name = 'list'
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^all/$', views.all_dates, name='all_dates'),
  url(r'^detail_date/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', views.detail_date, name='detail_date'),
]
```

Затем когда я перехожу по данной ссылке, я хочу увидеть все посты связанные с датой. Теперь о `detail_date` которому передается аргумент дата. Здесь я вывожу все посты предназначенные данному пользователю и фильтрую их по дате (нужны только те посты, которые созданы в данную дату)

```
@login_required
def detail_date(request, date):
  todos = Todo.objects.filter(owner=request.user, created_at=date).order_by('-created_at')
  return render(request, 'list/detail_date.html', {'todos':todos})
```

А detail_date.html выглядит так

```
{% for todo in todos %}
    <h1>{{ todo }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Здесь выводятся все посты, которые должны отфильтроваться по дате, но этого не получается, вместо этого я вижу пустую страницу и ошибку в терминале - `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Todo.created_at received a naive datetime (2019-01-08 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.`

Выдает пустую страницу при переходе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модель на всякий случай

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Todo(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю проблема в том, что в модели у вас поле **DateTimeField** - то есть и **дата плюс время**, которые автоматически задаются при создании объекта. Когда вы переходите по ссылке - вы передаёте **только дату** - поэтому получается, что **время передается 00:00:00**. А у базе у вас наверняка для той же даты что у вас в примере другая дата, поэтому появляется то предупреждение и нет объектов соответствующих фильтру. Измените поле в модели на:

```
created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: спасибо большое помогло! я так и думал что в этом проблема